# Android Studio project won't run in device

Tags: android, eclipse

I imported a project from Eclipse to Android studio. In emulator it runs, whereas when there's a device (rooted over WiFi), I get this message in the Event Log:

18:21:55 NumberFormatException: For input string: "": For input string: ""

And then an "internal IDE error".

What could I do before I switch back to Eclipse?

Stack trace:

```
For input string: "": For input string: ""
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.getDensity(Device.java:1220)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.getApk(AndroidRunningState.java:1022)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doPrepareAndStart(AndroidRunningState.java:915)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartApp(AndroidRunningState.java:876)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartAppWhenDeviceIsOnline(AndroidRunningState.java:844)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.doStart(AndroidRunningState.java:678)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState.start(AndroidRunningState.java:654)
    at org.jetbrains.android.run.AndroidRunningState$1.run(AndroidRunningState.java:299)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
fdfd
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the actual stack trace, as well as the relevant code pointed to by the stack trace.

Comment: I think its not ide problem....check whether your device mounted correctly or not and also check the string where numberFormatException happends?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I added the track trace

Comment: see what's at line 65.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet it's not my code. It's the IDE that crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new canary build of Android Studio 1.2, this is fixed.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like Android Studio crashed, not your code.

It sounds like you are running the debugger over wifi? 
If so, try it with the device plugged into the computer via usb.

I suspect that it has something to do with your 'debug over wifi' configuration - it looks like it's looking for a string containing a number, but getting an empty string. My best guess is that it's the specification of the port number, but could be the ip address..

Comment: I will take a look, but I really need debugging over WiFi. I don't see why it shouldn't work, since it uses the same adb commands. Perhaps the tools are incompatible with Studio ?